# Converting different date formats to single one in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

One of the STRING column of my table has both date formats "mm-dd-yyyy" and "yyyy-mm-dd". While selecting data I am trying to cast it to DATE format but it is giving me conversion error. I think this is because SQL can not convert 2 different formats at a time. How can I achieve this to get both formats converted to DATE in one go.

Comment: Rather than mopping the floor continuously, can you not fix the leak? I.e. change the column datatype to `date` and (if necessary) fix the application(s) that are inserting this data in the first place.

Comment: I wish I could. But data in string column is in "ABCD - 01-01-2016" format and this data is coming from application which is unfortunately not in my scope.  so while querying I do sub string of it and get only datepart from the same and then convert it into Date.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `date` datatype rather than storing these as strings anyway.

But you will still need code to convert to that.

You can use a `CASE` expression to toggle the style between 110 and 120

```
WITH T(Col) As
(
SELECT '04-01-2010' UNION ALL
SELECT '2010-04-01'
)
SELECT Col,
       CONVERT(date, Col,
       CASE WHEN COL LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then 110 
            WHEN COL LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]' then 120
        END
        )
FROM T
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct ,In one go u cannot cast DATE into two different format @ the same time. However looking into your question I would suggest you to analyse all the distinct DATE FORMATS in your column and try to write query as written below:

```
DECLARE @DATECol TABLE (DATEVAL varchar(20))
INSERT @DATECol VALUES ('2016-07-01'),('01/07/2016'),('01JULY2016'),('19/07/16'),('28-08-2008')

select 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(left(DATEVAL,4)) = 1 then CAST(DATEVAL as DATE) 
        WHEN LEN(DATEVAL) = 10 then CONVERT(DATE, DATEVAL, 103) 
        WHEN LEN(DATEVAL) = 8 then CONVERT(DATE, DATEVAL, 3) 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('/',DATEVAL) = 0 and ISNUMERIC(DATEVAL) = 0 then CONVERT(DATE, DATEVAL, 106) 
    END AS [Date] FROM @DATECol
```

Refer Link below for different DATE output formats http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Hope this Helps!